# Contents of a vector get deleted after every loop iteration

Tags: c++, loops, scope, c++17, global

I found out from another thread that apparently the objects defined within a specific iteration of a loop get deleted after the iteration is over. Hence I ran into a problem when I delete an element of a vector that is an attribute of a class object defined outside of the loop and after every iteration of the loop, the contents of the vector get deleted and replaced with some random gibberish numbers (and them the vector gets emptied out).

The code of the whole function is this

```
map<int, row*> solver(  map<int, row*> rowdict,
                        map<int, col*> coldict,
                        map<vector<int>, sqdiv*> sqdict  )
{
      for (int i_j_sum = 2;  i_j_sum <= 18; i_j_sum++)
      {
            for (int i=1; i <= i_j_sum-1; i++)
            {
                  vector<int> slot = {i, i_j_sum - i};  // j = i_j_sum - i
                  row rowobj =  *rowdict.at(i);
                  col colobj =  *coldict.at(i);
                  vector<int> sq_decider_ret = sq_decider(slot);
                  sqdiv sq = *sqdict.at(
                        sq_decider_ret
                  );

                  vector<int> tot_available = intersector(colobj.available, rowobj.available, sq.available);
                  int val = rand_from_vect(tot_available);

                  for (vector<int>::iterator it = colobj.available.begin(); it != colobj.available.end(); )
                  {
                        if (*it == val)
                              it = colobj.available.erase(it);
                        else
                              ++it;
                  }
                  for (vector<int>::iterator it = rowobj.available.begin(); it != rowobj.available.end(); )
                  {
                        if (*it == val)
                              it = rowobj.available.erase(it);
                        else
                              ++it;
                  }
                  for (vector<int>::iterator it = sq.available.begin(); it != sq.available.end(); )
                  {
                        if (*it == val)
                              it = sq.available.erase(it);
                        else
                              ++it;
                  }
                  // colobj.available = a; // remove(colobj.available, val);
                  // rowobj.available = b; // remove(rowobj.available, val);
                  // sq.available = c // remove(sq.available, val);

                  rowobj.slots.push_back(val);

                  coldict[i] = &colobj;
                  rowdict[i] = &rowobj;
                  sqdict[sq_decider_ret] = &sq;

            }
      }
      return rowdict;
}
```

Is there a way to define like a new vector from the inside of a loop and assign it to the object attribute but for it to be defined in the `global` scope or make the compiler not delete the contents of the vector?

Comment: You'd need to use dynamic memory allocation (using `new`) which raises the question why you have `map`s with raw pointer values. They should either be storing objects directly, or at least use a smart pointer like `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: Make it non-global (function local) static?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that everyone on Stackoverflow knows exactly what all the objects used, but not declared in the shown code are all about, and everyone knows what "object attribute" mean. Can you try to pretend that a complete stranger walked off the street and is standing in front of you, can you explain exactly what your question is? Something about a vector, but the shown code has clear problems with non-vector objects too. What they are is unclear, but it's pretty clear that what the program is doing with them is completely wrong. What is your ***precise*** question?

Comment: Please run the program with `valgrind` and fix all errors reported there. Then (and only then) it will make sense to debug it further.